# Show User location on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

First thing is I will tell you I am new to google maps and some of it is very confusing to me.  What I need to do is show a users location and have the appropriate markers show up.  I have the database all ready and somewhat of the Google map.

What I am working with is an example from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps?csw=1). What I can either get is the markers if I use a static LatLng or just the users dynamic location with no markers.

Need help please.  And if you downvote this post please let me know why.

Code I am using can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/8q1apmdy/9/ and show where in the blow code is where I am missing something, most likely small or in the wrong position.

```
function initMap() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
      });

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: pos,
          zoom: 12
          });         
}
```

Comment: @ I am able to display the markers from xml, in a different way

Comment: @soccerway ok mind sharing what that way would be?

Comment: I have shared my 'other' way of solving the problem. please see and reply.

Comment: @soccerway Hi, see my comment below

Comment: @soccerway I have updated the JSFiddle and getting closer to working, I think.  It asks for the user location but comes up with a blank screen.  It shows mapOption out of scope though..  https://jsfiddle.net/8q1apmdy/27/

Answer (score 0):

a) While running your code locally, I was getting 'pos' undefined, so I moved the following code '*var map = new google.maps.Map(..*' inside the getCurrentPosition(){...
b) Then I got another error ' InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map;' so created a 'var map' globally.
Loaded the map successfully, but still markers were not loaded. while debugging your code at this point '*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...*' it is iterating for all markers from xml but somehow markers are not adding to the map..dont know the reason yet?

So I have tried in a different way. Please see all markers from xml displayed on map. Here I am just getting the '*name*' in marker, you might need to add other parameters like *id, address* etc.
JSFiddle added for reference

```
var infowindow;
var map;
 //var downloadUrl;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.868820, 151.209290),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      downloadUrl("https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml", function(data) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');        
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var id =  markers[i].getAttribute('id');              
              var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
              var type = markers[i].getAttribute('type');
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          bounds.extend(latlng);
          var marker = createMarker(id, markers[i].getAttribute("name"), address, latlng, type);
        }//finish loop
        //map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }); //end downloadurl
      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    }

    function createMarker(id, name, address, latlng, type) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                               position: latlng,                               
                               map: map
                               });
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: name});
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
       });
       return marker;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/8q1apmdy/15/)

Comment: Sorry, but one thing and I probably didn't make this clear in my first question.  I need a dynamic user location for this and not in just one sport but anywhere in a country.  The mapmarkers2.xml file is just for reference right now but it will contain info across the country and that's why I need it to show the user location.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean dynamic location? Will each user accessing the google map page? If yes, whenever there is a location change, you need to get their location details and send that to the server and save into a database. From the database, you pull the location as json or xml every short interval of time and display on map. But be aware, this activity will create/send more request to Google map ( ie 25000 request / day for free quota and above they will charge I guess). Need to think about database pooling too. Please accept my answer for if it ans the first question.

Comment: I am not sure why I would have to store the location into a database.  I have tried to use the following goolge tutorial but it a couple of years old and I know there are some changes that make it not work on current php.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Comment: Yes, you don't need to store location data in database if you don't want see previous location info or history of data. Another option is to call an ajax POST method and send the location details to server. Once the server get location details send back to map. Call a another ajax GET method to display the markers on map